# Ssl Certificate Http to Https too many redirects

Tags: asp.net, ssl, web-config, http-redirect

I added SSL to my website

I added rewrite rule to redirect https.

Web.config

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
     <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"  
           redirectType="Permanent" />
     </rule>
  </rules>

</rewrite>
```

Now, I'am getting error :
Too Many Redirects

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem.

If you are using Cloudflare change option like this :

Go Cloudflare > Crypto > SSL > Full (strict)

After a few hour your problem will be solved.